# Edit bytes in pdf file

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I need to convert from a grayscale PDF in RGB to CMYK. So i just create an uncompressed PDF in iText and then replace all entries like "0.7 0.7 0.7 RB" with "0.0 0.0 0.0 0.7 K".

It works fine but when i open pdf in Acrobat Reader i see a message like "PDF is damaged, but can be opened". Then pdf looks fine. I suppose is some safaty machanism in PDF-Format, like hash. Can i somehow avoid this message?

P.S. Generate pdf direct in CMYK is not an option, because i use PdfGraphics2D to draw my AWT Components, and PdfGraphics2D can only RGB.

Comment: so in other words: you are treating a PDF like a BMP and get a random-generator?

Comment: no, i treat a uncompressed pdf as text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PDF files contain cross-reference tables and/or one or more cross-reference streams. Basically, such a table/stream contains information about PDF object offsets from the start of the file.

When you replace `0.7 0.7 0.7 RB` with `0.0 0.0 0.0 0.7 K` you are changing byte size of page streams and render values stored in cross-reference stream incorrect.

Many PDF processors are used to deal with PDF files broken in such a way but you certainly trying to fit squares into round holes :-)

Please use a tool that can do the task properly. I guess, Acrobat Professional should do what you need just fine. Or at least update cross-reference table (might be not an easy task).

Another option is to hack up some broken PDFs and then *open them in Acrobat and save*.Acrobat will update cross-reference table for you.

But please-please-please don't let such broken PDFs into the wild.

Comment: unfortunately to post-edit pdf in some external app is not an option, i need make all the work in my java code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are working with grayscale values, just try to convert RGB to CMYK in this other way:

RGB (0.7, 0.7, 0.7) -> CMYK (0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.0)